# MySQL Query : Match comma separated value with column containing comma separted string

Tags: mysql

I have a user table containing a column(say interests) with comma separated interest ids as a value.
e.g.

```
user  interests
A     12,13,15
B     10,11,12,15
C     9,13
D     10,12
```

Now, I have a string with comma separated values as "13,15".

I want to fetch the users who has the interest 13,15 from above table means it should return the user A, B & C as user A contains both interest(13,15), user B matched the interest with 15 & user matched the interest with 13.

what will be the SQL as I have a lots of users in my table.

Comment: Storing values as csv is very bad db design. Learn about normalization.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be done with regexp as @1000111 said, but with more complicated regexp. Look at this, for example:

```
(^|,)(13|15)(,|$)
```

This will not match 13 from 135, or 1 from 13 and so on. For example, for number 13 this will match next strings:

```
1,13,2
13,1,2
1,13
13,2
13
```

But will not match these

```
1,135,2
131,2
1,113
```

And this is query:

```sql
SET @search = '13,15';

SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE interests REGEXP CONCAT('(^|,)(', REPLACE(@search, ',', '|'), ')(,|$)')
```

Comment: Thanks, save my day

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the result based on loose matching then you can follow this query:

Loose matching means interests like `135,151` would also appear while searching for '13,15'.

```
SET @inputInterest := "13,15";

SELECT 
*
FROM userinterests
WHERE interests REGEXP REPLACE(@inputInterest,',','|');
```

For the given data you will get an output like below:

```
| ID | user |   interests |
|----|------|-------------|
|  1 |    A |    12,13,15 |
|  2 |    B | 10,11,12,15 |
|  3 |    C |        9,13 |
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23f4f/1/1)

**EDIT:**

If you want result based on having at least one of the interests exactly then you can use regex as @Andrew mentioned in this answer:

Here's I've modified my query based on his insight:

```
SET @inputInterest := "13,15";

SELECT 
*
FROM userinterests
WHERE interests REGEXP CONCAT('(^|,)(', REPLACE(@inputInterest, ',', '|'), ')(,|$)')
```

[**SEE DEMO OF IT**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23f4f/2/1)

**Note:**

You need to replace the `@inputInterest` variable by your input string.

**Suggestion:**

[**Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: May I know the reason behind downvoting?

Comment: Downvoted. This will not work in general case. What if we need to search interests '1,2'? 1 will be found, 10, 11, 12, 22 etc.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I just thought the straightforward way. @Andrew

Comment: You are right. I've edited my answer based on the flaw pointed out by Andrew @Andrew